# Facing issue while login redirect

Tags: angular, azure, user-interface, authentication, azure-ad-msal

I have an angular app which uses @azure/msal-angular package to authenticate. I am facing issue in creating sso from other site to my site. For exa:
If i login into microsoft learning site and then i try to login into my site, it shows me the list of the accounts i can use to continue.
Is there any way possible that i can make it continue directly with logged in account in current session.

I tried to manually update the url and set prompt variable as none then it works. But i am facing issue to set it automatically through code. I tried to pass prompt in extra query parameters but it says duplicate entry.

```
 constructor(public router: Router,private
    appservice:appService,private msl:MsalService) {}   
    canActivate():boolean {
        //debugger;
          if(!this.appservice.isAuthenticated()){
          this.msl.loginRedirect();
          return true;
        }
        return true;   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `acquireTokenSilent` uses a hidden iframe with `prompt=none` which means the user will not be prompted for credentials. This API relies on the session cookie established between the browser and AAD to obtain a new access_token. If your session is expired , this API call will fail and you will have to do an interactive token renewal by calling either `acquireTokenPopup` or `acquireTokenRedirect` where you will be asked to enter your credentials again.

It might be possible that your browser is dropping the cookie`(x-ms-cpim-transdoes)`.

Also we have seen this in Safari browser too for Mac users and issue was related to the setting of Safari **`Preferences -> Privacy -> Prevent cross-site tracking`**

you can check the below thread for similar issue.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/349

Comment: Hi Mohit, the issue is fixed in latest version of msal.js. But the latest version of @azure/msal-angular is still using the older version of msal.js where prompt is hardcoded with 'select account'.  Team has responded back saying they will be releasing a new package soon. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Sure , will check with the concerned engineer and keep you updated with the progress.